# Flutter: Allow communication between two Flutter apps installed on same phone

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Suppose you have two Flutter apps: A and B.

I want app A to call app B with arguments. App B will perform some logic and return a response to app A.

I understand that Flutter allows the use of Platform Channels, but, as far as I can tell, that's when you want to call platform-specific APIs.

Can Flutter apps be called externally with arguments and return a response to caller?

Comment: It is possible with android using startactivityforresult and setresult.

Comment: it is possible through flutter packages or storing data in a database provided by firebase